# PHP assign global value the reference of another global value inside a function

Tags: php, reference, global

While playing around with globals and references in PHP I came across a problem. I wanted to set a variable to the reference of another variable inside a function. To my surprise, the global variable lost its reference after the function call.

In the code below you can see that inside the function `$a` gets the value `5`, but afterwards it has its old value back (`1`). `$x` on the other hand has kept the value assigned inside the function.

```
<?php

$a = 1;
$x = 2;
function test() {
    global $a;
    global $x;

    $a = &$x;
    $x = 5;

    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo $a . PHP_EOL;
    echo $x . PHP_EOL;
}

test();

echo PHP_EOL;
echo $a . PHP_EOL; // $a is 1 here instead of 5
echo $x . PHP_EOL;

$a = &$x;

echo PHP_EOL;
echo $a . PHP_EOL;
echo $x . PHP_EOL;
```

Outputs:

```
5
5

1
5

5
5
```

Why does `$a` lose its reference after the function is done?

Comment: I'm not proficient in globals, as these are evil. I think you need to define global on first declaration of `$a`, ie before function definition.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything unfortunately

Comment: As I know global vars can be changed via `$GLOBAL` array, I mean instead of `$a` you need to use `$GLOBALS[$a]` if you want to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Banzay noticed,  I believe `$a = &$x;` only changes the function-scoped variable. You should use [`$GLOBALS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) to change the value in a function;

```
function test() {
    global $a;
    global $x;

    $GLOBALS['a'] = &$x;
    $x = 5;

    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo $a . PHP_EOL;
    echo $x . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Try online!](https://3v4l.org/dSDPb)

```
1
5

5
5

5
5
```

Comment: That seems to work, although I still find it weird that $x can be changed with a static variable but $a can't with a reference.